# Interractive Gantt chart drawing

Tags: interactive, gantt-chart

I need to develop an application that can draw a Gantt chart and the elements can be moved and edited with the mouse.
Which programming language is the most suitable for this and what extra libraries are needed?
Can this be done with C++ or python?